# convert dataframe column values and apply SHA2 masking logic

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, scala-collections

I have a dataframe that contains the Property table and main table from Hive. I want to remove columns and then I want to apply masking logic (SHA2).

Reading Property config from postgre DB as a Dataframe in Spark/scala job.

[image: 1]

`val propertydf = loading the property dataframe from postgre db`

**Main Hive table**

[image: 2]

and the output should be

[image: 3]

Anyone,  please help me write a code in Spark/Scala. I am unable to convert List[String] and pass it to function from dataframe config.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can manipulate the column names and select them as appropriate:

```
val masking = propertydf.head(1)(0).getAs[String]("maskingcolumns").split(",")
val exclude = propertydf.head(1)(0).getAs[String]("columnstoexclude").split(",")

val result = df.select(
    masking.map(c => sha2(col(c).cast("string"), 256).as(c)) ++ 
    df.columns.filterNot(c => masking.contains(c) || exclude.contains(c)).map(col)
    :_*
)

result.show(false)
+----------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------+---+---+
|a                                                               |b                                                               |c  |d  |
+----------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------+---+---+
|ba7816bf8f01cfea414140de5dae2223b00361a396177a9cb410ff61f20015ad|6b86b273ff34fce19d6b804eff5a3f5747ada4eaa22f1d49c01e52ddb7875b4b|11 |cbc|
+----------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------+---+---+
```